# Scope question, var undefined in nested function

Tags: javascript

I return a json map from a servlet using this get call. I create a var i = 0; to count the users returned in the data. I am easily able to use i as in `jsondata[i]` to access the users returned. But then below I try to use the same json and var inside the nested function of a click handler and it gives undefined. I looked [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/) and it says:

> Each function has its own scope, and any variable declared within that function is only accessible from that function and any nested functions. Because local scope in JavaScript is created by functions, it’s also called function scope. When we put a function inside another function, then we create nested scope.

so why is i undefined in the click handler ? If I change `console.log(jsondata[i]);` to `console.log(jsondata[0]);` I see the correct information rather than undefined.

```
$.get("/lod1/Scuttlebutt",{name:"onload",data: -1},function(jsondata) {
    var numberofusers = jsondata.length;
    var i = 0;
    $(".mate").each(function(index) {
        //show
        $(this).css("display","block");
        //construct new id
        var mateid = 'mate'+jsondata[i][0].userid;
        //create ids for this mate
        $(this).attr('id',mateid+"MateContainer");
        $(this).find(".mateavatar").attr("id",mateid+"avatar");
        $(this).find("#matename").attr("id",mateid+"Name");
        $(this).find("#matepoints").attr("id",mateid+"Points");
        $(this).find("#matesensignia").attr("id",mateid+"Ensignia");
        $(this).find("#matebio").attr("id",mateid+"Bio");
        $(this).find("#matesets").attr("id",mateid+"Sets");
        $(this).find("#matebadges").attr("id",mateid+"Badges");
        //fill in correct info
        $(this).find("#"+mateid+"Name").text(jsondata[i][0].userName);
        $(this).find("#"+mateid+"Points").text(jsondata[i][0].points);
        $(this).find("#"+mateid+"Ensignia").attr('src',calculateEnsignia(jsondata[i][0].rank));

            //add onclick handler to username
            $(this).find("#"+mateid+"Name").on('click',function(){
                console.log(jsondata[i]);
                var num_tabs = $("div#tabmenu ul li").length + 1;

                $("div#tabmenu ul").append(
                    "<li><a href='#tab" + mateid + "'>" + jsondata[i][0].userName + "</a></li>"
                );
                $("div#tabmenu").append(
                    "<div id='tab" + mateid + "'> NEW TAB!</div>"
                );
                $("div#tabmenu").tabs("refresh");
            });
```

Comment: Add `console.log(i)` to verify the value of `i`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Aha i is '2' there, not undefined.

Comment: So it's only adding the click handler after the iterations are done, that makes sense thanks

Comment: did you fix it? can you show the full code please? maybe you are not iterating through jsondata properly

Comment: @Charis Theo for some reason setting the click handler outside of .each() made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will only work after the click event

> console.log(jsondata[i])

What you can do , you can use any other ways to determine the index of your row then you can use it to get your data